# How to make 1row to 2rows GridView in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview, row, datagridviewcolumn

I have GridView with 5 items like this.

[image]

I want to make this GridView as below big red square. How can I make 2rows in one GridView?

[image]

### ASP Code :

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" DataSourceID="GridView1" 
    OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="표시할 내용없음">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Seq"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UUSER" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NoticeDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SCnt" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

#### C#

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
        e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
        e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;
        e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = false;
        e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = false;
        //e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("colspan", "2");
    }
```

Comment: Am i the only one who doesn't see the images? You should use a different image hoster.

Comment: No, i have tried it before. They are loading forever.

Comment: @TimSchmelter how about [here](http://blog.naver.com/naan_ace/220297020870). This is my blog... It should be shown.

Comment: Yes, it shows. But what are the images there?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I changed background color to orange of posting. It says First, and Second. If it doesn't work... OTL......

Comment: If it was possible to see the url of the images i could upload them to stackoverflow. But you use that photo viewer which prevents that.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ah... So you changed my edit now you can see! It was first time to use image.. hard to me hh. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Even after i've uploaded them to stackoverflow they could not be loaded. Now i've linked them from google+ and it works. However, it's not so clear what you are trying to do. You have a datasource with a single record?  You don't want a headerrow? But the 3-5 column should be in the second row?  Or do you have many records and you always want to wrap the columns3-5 into the next row?

Comment: @TimSchmelter ah.. okay. I didn't understand about GridView and should search and study basic about that more. Thanks a ton about your help and point out what's problem my question. I'll upload again soon.